# Limit user to enter a competition 5 times every 24 hours?

Tags: php, facebook, forms

I have built a Facebook app for a client, this app allows the user to enter their details and guess a figure to be entered into a competition. The app is run via an iframe.

Is there any possible way of only letting the user submit the form 5 times maximum within 24 hours (preferably by facebook profile or IP address), then echo an error if they try to enter a 6th time. I have a php script that gathers the data and exports it to a csv file.

PHP form code:

```
<?php
if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")
{
    $errorMessage = "";

  if(empty($_POST['formName']))
  {
    $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter your name.</li>";
  }
  if(empty($_POST['formTown']))
  {
    $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter your town.</li>";
  }
  if(empty($_POST['formEmail']))
  {
    $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter your email.</li>";
  }

    $varName = $_POST['formName'];
    $varTown = $_POST['formTown'];
    $varAge = $_POST['formAge'];
    $varEmail = $_POST['formEmail'];

    $varOne = $_POST['hidden-one'];
    $varTwo = $_POST['hidden-two'];
    $varThree = $_POST['hidden-three'];
    $varFour = $_POST['hidden-four'];
    $varFive = $_POST['hidden-five'];

    if(empty($errorMessage)) 
    {
        $fs = fopen("mydata.csv","a");
        fwrite($fs,"\n" . $varName . ", " . $varTown . ", " . $varAge . ", " . $varEmail . ", " . $varOne . $varTwo . $varThree . $varFour . $varFive);
        fclose($fs);

        header("Location: thankyou.php");
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution is to log form submits to a database. For each submit you log the time and an identifier for the user (IP address, Facebook account, etc). This data can be used to check how many times the user submitted the form in the last 24 hours. If this is more than X times, you do not store the data and inform the user.

But this solution assumes you have access to a database.

Comment: Sorry, wouldn't work as I need it to export straight to a csv. We have a system set-up over here that will automatically pick a winner etc ... I need a way to do it without using a database...

Comment: I understand you need the data as a CSV file, but you can separate the logging of the form submits from the data gathering. You check the database if the form submit is valid, and if the form submit is valid you write the data to the CSV file, just as you are doing now. If the user already submitted the form 5 times in the last 24 hours, you just do not write to the CSV file.